# I need a Python regex to tokenize the sentences upon finding a "\\n"

Tags: python, regex

I used a document converter to get the text from PDF. The text appears in the form:

> "Hello Programmers\\nToday we will learn how to create a program in
>   python\\nThefirst task is very easy and the level will exponentially
>   increase\\nso please bare in mind that this course is not for the
>   weak hearted\\n"

I am using NLTK to tokenize the document into sentence upon occurrence of `\\n`. I have used the below regex, but it doesn't work.

Please excuse me if the regex is wrong, I am new to it.

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'^[\n]')

>>> tokens
[]
```

..

```
#tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer('\\n')

>>> tokens
['\n']
>>>
```

Even using `\\n` did not work. How can I write a correct regex?

Comment: Try `tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\\n')`

Comment: No use. I have tried it before. It gives me the result ['\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', ' '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n']

Comment: You need escape the backslashes. Try this: `'\\\\n'`

Comment: If there are 2 literal backslashes before `n`, then you need `r'\\\\n'`. Haven't you posted a regular (non-raw) string literal?

Comment: tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\\\\n') gives an empty list

Comment: unless i'm mistaken about the objective, yourtext.split("\\n") is the best way to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you need to use `gaps`

```
>>> tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\\n', gaps=True)
>>> tokenizer.tokenize(s)
['Hello Programmers', 'Today we will learn how to create a program in python', 'Thefirst task is very easy and the level will exponentially increase', 'so please bare in mind that this course is not for the weak hearted']
```

A `RegexpTokenizer` splits a string into substrings using a regular expression. A RegexpTokenizer can use its regexp to match delimiters instead using `gaps=True`

Comment: As I said, the pattern is `r'\\n'` :) Maybe `discard_empty=True` will also be useful. I was writing an answer, but you were quicker. Surely `gaps` is the key here.

Comment: Actually if you don't use `gaps` tokenizer will match the pattern 
`>>> tokenizer.tokenize(s)
['\\n', '\\n', '\\n', '\\n']`

Comment: Thanks a ton !! This worked. Don't have enough rep to upvote but I'll definitely do it once my rep goes up. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

The most basic solution which may be useful is:

```
text = "Hello Programmers\\nToday we will learn how to create a program in python\\nThefirst task is very easy and the level will exponentially increase\\nso please bare in mind that this course is not for the weak hearted\\n"

each_line = text.split('\\n')

for i in each_line:
    print i
```